# After submitting dropdownlist there is an error MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist, after submitting there is an error http://prntscr.com/lnagi8

This is the View

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAgrBall, Model.agrBall)
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
```

and this is Controller (Post)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Main(string Years, string Periods, Organisations m)
{
    string s = m.SelectedAgrBall;
    int ss = int.Parse(s);
    string t = Years;
    string b = Periods;
    return View();
}
```

What should i do?
Controller

```
public ActionResult Main()
    {
        aspregistrationEntities1 obj = new aspregistrationEntities1();

        List<agrBal> aggrBad = obj.agrBals.ToList();
        List<agrBReceiv> aggrRec = obj.agrBReceivs.ToList();

        SortedSet<string> org = new SortedSet<string>();
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Dictionary<int, string> orgNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (agrBal tmp in aggrBad)
        {
            org.Add(tmp.ORG.ToString());
        }
        foreach(agrBReceiv tmp in aggrRec)
        {
            orgNames.Add(int.Parse(tmp.PBS.ToString()), tmp.KBO_RU.ToString());
        }

        //Drop organisations in dropdownlist
        var types = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (string tmp in org)
        {
            string s = tmp+" - "+orgNames[int.Parse(tmp)];
            SelectListItem item1 = new SelectListItem() { Text = s, Value = tmp.ToString() };
            items.Add(item1);
        }

        Organisations m = new Organisations() {
             agrBall= items
        };
        return View(m);
    }
```

Model

```
{
public class Organisations
{
    public List<SelectListItem> agrBall { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAgrBall { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: what is Model.agrBall ? Unless it's a collection of select list items, you will probably need to modify your DropDownListFor line

Comment: And the error looks to be on the page render, not the submit

Comment: If you post your model class, as well as your HttpGet controller method, I might be able to help

Comment: "public List<SelectListItem> agrBall { get; set; }" it is Model.agrBall there is info for dropdownlist.

Comment: I have poster controller method.

Comment: And this error only occurs when you click the submit button right?

Comment: Yes there is error after pressing submit button.

Comment: Are your View HTML controls inside of a <form> tag?

Comment: Yes View HTML controls are inside of a <form> tag.

Comment: Actually... did you give furkanhb's answer a try? That might be it, I'm just having trouble trying to narrow down your issue without stepping through the debugger

Comment: I have tried furkanhb's answre and there was new error http://prntscr.com/lnbe4p.

Comment: That's because it assigns the value to your string when it posts back, but then can't convert that string value back into a select list item when re-rendering with the item already selected. You declare SelectedAgrBall as a select list item and then set "string s = m.SelectedAgrBall.Value;"

Answer (score 1):

You return View without model on HttpPost action so null reference exception occurs because you're using Model object in Main.cshtml

You should pass the model object to view.

(I think) if your model is `Organizations m` like that

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Main(string Years, string Periods, Organisations m)
    {
        string s = m.SelectedAgrBall;
        int ss = int.Parse(s);
        string t = Years;
        string b = Periods;
        return View(m);
    }
```

Comment: I change code like return View(m); and there is new error http://prntscr.com/lnbe4p.

Answer (score 0):

Followed furkanhb and then modified the model/post method to allow for reloading of the page with a pre-selected value

```
public class Organisations
{
    public List<SelectListItem> agrBall { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem SelectedAgrBall { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Main(string Years, string Periods, Organisations m)
{
    string s = m.SelectedAgrBall.Value;
    int ss = int.Parse(s);
    string t = Years;
    string b = Periods;
    return View(m);
}
```